# Barplot with subgroup of different width

Tags: bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

I have some scenarion data with different amount of subscenarion. But the sub scenarios are not same. Like scenario 1 has 7 subscenarion, 2 has 3 while scenario 3 has only only 1.

Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12t4dc0AjbfBJqTgX8jCShKZhXhedPjNt/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104032419242527342985&rtpof=true&sd=true

I have also add the data as an image. [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRZkC.png)

When I tried to plot all scenarios had same width, like 7 lines for scenarion 1 cummilatively have the same width as one line in scenarion 3 (Picture attached for a different dataset).
I have also attached a drawn picture of how the barchart should be.[Plot with a different Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ohBd.png)
[How the plot should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt5wR.jpg)

Comment: this question is better asked at math or stats exchange https://stats.stackexchange.com